# Cannot make git push origin master

Tags: git, github

can someone help me please? I am writing git push -u origin master and boom. This is the all error i received. I don't really understand this, where is the problem.

```
C:\row1\dev\LoginApp [master]> git push -u origin master
remote: Permission to ramixxx/LoginApp.git denied to 54ef768b13d2e587d9deebc1dc68997a2d13941e.
fatal: unable to access 'https://github.com/ramixxx/LoginApp.git/': The requested URL returned error: 403
```

Comment: Did you use **runas**?

Comment: No, I am using Git Shell.

Comment: Did you use **sudo?** git push -f

Comment: no i used
git init, 
git add . , 
git commit -m "...", 
git remote add origin (link to project),
git remote -v,
git push -u origin master

Comment: if i try git push -f it says : fatal: The current branch master has no upstream branch.
To push the current branch and set the remote as upstream, use

    git push --set-upstream origin master

Comment: When i try git push -f it says : fatal: The current branch master has no upstream branch.
To push the current branch and set the remote as upstream, use

    git push --set-upstream origin master

Comment: what do you get when you type `git remote -v`?

Comment: I get : origin  https://github.com/ramixxx/LoginApp.git (fetch)
origin  https://github.com/ramixxx/LoginApp.git (push)

Answer (score 0):

The 403 response is "Not Authorized" so you have a permissions problem with GitHub. Most likely you haven't set up your SSH keys properly. This might help: [Generating SSH Keys](https://help.github.com/articles/generating-ssh-keys/)

Or, if it prompted you for a username and password on push, then you may have entered it incorrectly. [This GitHub help page](https://help.github.com/articles/which-remote-url-should-i-use/#cloning-with-https-recommended) also has some info on setting up credentials.

Comment: I've generated and made the SSH key after that tutorial. When i try to make push it even dont ask for username or password, but the error.